# Angular - Having trouble to getting desired html output

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular project, I have a div with 3 child elements which are a `span`, an `i` element (icon) and a `span` with innerHTML attribute. Normally, all texts should be in the same line, but innerHtml code always starts with `p` and I can do nothing about it, so this causes a problem. Any suggestions?

**This is my output:**

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #DDD; padding: 3px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <span>2020.07.10</span>
  <i>icon</i>
  <span><p>This is an example text. This is an example text.</p></span>
</div>
```

**This is desired output:**

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #DDD; padding: 3px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <span>2020.07.10</span>
  <i>icon</i>
  <span>This is an example text. This is an example text.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p>` is a block element and you covered it by `span`(inline). Add `style="display: inline;"` to `<p>` element. Browsers automatically add a single blank line before and after each `<p>` element.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #DDD; padding: 3px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <span>2020.07.10</span>
  <i>icon</i>
  <span><p style="display: inline;">This is an example text. This is an example text.</p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't want to touch innerHTML code, because of that I've asked this question but I guess I have to do it. Thank you, Roman.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "innerHtml code always starts with p and I can do nothing about it."

If you entered this markup yourself, you can just omit the p tag.

If you are getting this html from a CMS or database, and you can do nothing about the p tag that's in there, then:

1. Your question maybe should include the binding, not just the output.
2. You can let the p tag exist, but add CSS to make it do nothing.  In the snippet below, I replaced your inline styles with a CSS class "myDiv", and put in a rule to render the p tag useless.

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid #DDD; 
  padding: 3px; 
  width: 50%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myDiv span p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <span>2020.07.10</span>
  <i>icon</i>
  <span><p>This is an example text. This is an example text.</p></span>
</div>
```